# Bit Operations in Simulink

Tags: bit-manipulation, simulink

I am in process of converting C code to simulink based function. I came across a statement for clearing a bit at a particular position.

For Example:

```
        samples = samples & (~(1<<(sampleCnt)));
```

I can do the shift using the Shift block in simulink but a logical complement of the bits is not available. What is the best way to go about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Bitwise Operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/bitwiseoperator.html) block, and choose `NOT`.

Comment: The description for NOT on the website is the following:
`TRUE if the input is FALSE (available only for single input)`

Would't this be a logical NOT? Any non zero number would be returned a zero? What my intention would be  ~(5) = 2

Comment: No.  It is a bit-wise NOT.  For instance if you input `uint8(1)`, that is `00000001` the output will be `uint8(254)` which is `11111110`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the description on the website is not exactly clear.